# assembly working with registers and variables

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I have these variables:

```
A DB 56h
B DW -123
C DB '$'
```

Then I have 4 operations:

```
add C,al
add ax,A
add B,al
add C,ax
```

Only the first one is the correct one. Can anyone explain me why those 3 operations are wrong? (I know they are wrong because of different sizes but I don't know those sizes)

Comment: Doesn't the assembler generate warnings?

Comment: Yes, it does. But if I have to know which operation is correct without using any software.

Comment: *" I don't know the sizes"*. You do: `DB` is 1 byte, `DW` is 2 bytes, `al` is 1 byte, `ax` is 2 bytes.

Comment: so what's wrong e.g. with add ax,A? ax = 2 bytes,  DB - 1 byte; 56h = 2 bytes?

Comment: The assembler told you it's wrong, and you'll  have to find another assembler, or processor, if you don't like it. `A` is only one byte, as I mentioned. Normally you have to do arithmetic on same-size operands.

Comment: ah now I understand, thanks.

Comment: In particular `add C,ax` is trying to fit "a quart into a pint pot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the possible ways of creating variables in assembly

```
 `DB       Define Byte       allocates 1 byte 
  DW      Define Word       allocates 2 bytes
  DD      Define Doubleword allocates 4 bytes
  DQ      Define Quadword   allocates 8 bytes
  DT      Define Ten Bytes  allocates 10 bytes`
```

Registers are fixed tiny storage spaces inside the processors with which the processor can directly work on 
And these are the available registers in x86 based assembly.

```
  `ax => [ah + al] 
  bx => [bh + bl]
  cx => [ch + cl]
  dx => [dh + dl]`
```

Of which ax,bx,cx and dx are 16 bit registers that can be referenced as such, or the individual pair of 8 bits can be used separately, and those can be referenced using ah,al,bh,..etc where the `h` in `ah,bh` etc. stands for `"higher"` byte of the corresponding 16 bit registers(ax,bx,cx,dx) and the `l` in `al,bl` etc. stands for the lower byte  
To do arithmetic operations or transfers between two variables ,they should be of the same size

because the size of `DB` depends on the string passed in. ie. a byte per character, in the above example the variable C is of 1 byte, which is same as that of al - which is the lower byte of ax register.

To see more info about the allocation of variables in assembly, try this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_registers.htm)